# ArcGIS API for Javascript Not Adding Layer and/or Graphic during mouse event handler?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers

I am trying to add a graphic to my graphics layer during a map mouse event. In the javascript console, I can see that my graphic object is created and no error is thrown when I add the graphic to my graphics layer. However, when I try to add the graphics layer to the map, nothing happens. Same thing happens when I try to do a map.graphics.add(graphic) function.  Has anyone else run into this? Or is there a workaround for this issue?

Here's my code:

```js
app.map.on("mouse-drag",function(evt){

    if(evt.ctrlKey){  //control key must be pressed

        var polygonSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(); //create the symbol for the graphic
        var polygon = new Polygon(makeArc(evt));  //create the polygon the the returned geometry from makeArc()
        var graphic = new Graphic(polygon,polygonSymbol); //create the graphic objet
        console.log(graphic); 
        gLayer.add(graphic); //add the graphic to the graphic layer
        app.map.addLayer(gLayer); //add the graphic layer to the map
    }

});
```

Also, I know that it is not being added because I can't see the html inside the map div after the event occurs, which I usually can when I add a graphic or layer.

Answer (score 1):

Give the polygonSymbol a definition in the constructor

```js
var polygonSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
  new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT,
  new esri.Color([255,0,0]), 2), new esri.Color([255,255,0,0.25]));
```

More information here on creating a fill symbol

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/simplefillsymbol-amd.html#simplefillsymbol2